# Google API Geocode using JavaScript error when run

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, requirejs, geocode

I am attempting to print out an address on the console log. However, when I run the code I end up getting an error stating that

```
{
   "error_message" : "Invalid request. Missing the 'address', 'components', 'latlng' or 'place_id' parameter.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

I use an npm module called **request** and am trying to simply print out the address onto the log. I've tried other addresses and keep on running into the same issue. What exactly am I missing here ?

```
const request = require('request');

    request({
      url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address%20=%201301%20lombard%20street%20philadelphia',
      //json = true
    }, (error, response, body) => {
      console.log(body);
    });
```

The formatting seems to be correct, based on the first example given in the link https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Answer (score 0):

Remove the %20 (space) after address in the link :)

Comment: When I do that the error I get is different.                                                                                                                {
   "error_message" : "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

Answer (score 0):

I use other Google Maps API so going try to help you.
Please use your target address in 'address=1301%20lombard%20street%20philadelphia' format

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1301%20lombard%20street%20philadelphia&key=PASTE_YOUR_API_KEY`

You will need API key. Head over to : `https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key`

your response will be :

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1301",
               "short_name" : "1301",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Lombard Street",
               "short_name" : "Lombard St",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Washington Square West",
               "short_name" : "Washington Square West",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Philadelphia",
               "short_name" : "Philadelphia",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Philadelphia County",
               "short_name" : "Philadelphia County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Pennsylvania",
               "short_name" : "PA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "19147",
               "short_name" : "19147",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "1003",
               "short_name" : "1003",
               "types" : [ "postal_code_suffix" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1301 Lombard St, Philadelphia, PA 19147, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 39.9444071,
               "lng" : -75.16317189999999
            },
            "location_type" : "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 39.9457560802915,
                  "lng" : -75.16182291970848
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 39.9430581197085,
                  "lng" : -75.16452088029151
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "EiwxMzAxIExvbWJhcmQgU3QsIFBoaWxhZGVscGhpYSwgUEEgMTkxNDcsIFVTQSIbEhkKFAoSCU38VoEkxsaJEedji1ij51aUEJUK",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```